# pyopencl - how to use generic types?

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I work Interchangeably with 32 bit floats and 32 bit integers. I want two kernels that do exactly the same thing, but one is for integers and one is for floats. At first I thought I could use templates or something, but it does not seem possible to specify two kernels with the same name but different argument types?

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void arange(__global int *res_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  res_g[gid] = gid;
}

__kernel void arange(__global float *res_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  res_g[gid] = gid;
}
""").build()
```

Error:

```
<kernel>:8:15: error: conflicting types for 'arange'
__kernel void arange(__global float *res_g)
              ^
<kernel>:2:15: note: previous definition is here
__kernel void arange(__global int *res_g)
```

What is the most convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` directive can be used for that:

```
code = """ 
__kernel void arange(__global TYPE *res_g)
{
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  res_g[gid] = gid;
}
"""

prg_int = cl.Program(ctx, code).build("-DTYPE=int")
prg_float = cl.Program(ctx, code).build("-DTYPE=float")
```

Comment: Good solution, can this be used in the same way as c++ macros?

Comment: OpenCL is a subset of C so these are C macros which are the same like C++ which inherited them from C.